# Linux graphical password dialog trick security

Tags: linux, security, password, sudo, gui

When we run a command by sudo, the password is asked

```
[sudo] password for user
```

If the sudo is not typed the password should not be asked. If asked, I would assume it as a fraud by the application.

How about graphical applications which ask us password through a GUI? If asked for password, how can we differentiate between Linux original password dialogue or a dialogue generated by the application to look like Linux one?

[image: Authentication dialog]

Answer (score 1):

When I worry about this, I run `sudo -k; sudo date && sudo -n wooden-horse-command`. Then I'll be prompted for the password exactly once (by `sudo date`), and the sudo ticket should be fresh for the following command.

Not that this gains much in terms of security, you understand. A malicious program that installs a keylogger will be more effective at grabbing your password, even if it isn't run as root.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to run `ps -A` or `ps aux` to see what the corresponding process could be if you feel suspicious. Then bring up the original password gui prompt, do a `ps` again and compare it to the 'suspicious' one.